# A doubt on the definition of direct sum of two vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose $X$ is a vector space and $V$ and $W$ are subspaces. Now, consider the cartesian product of $V$ and $W$ with the addition and scalar multiplication defined (so that $V \times W$ forms a vector space). If $X$ and $V \times W$ are isomorphic, is it true that $V \cap W$=$\{0\}$ where $0$ is the identity of $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $V$ and $W$ be each equal to the subspace generated by $(1,0)$. Then $X$ is isomorphic to $V\times W$, for each has dimension $2$. But $V\cap W\ne \{0\}$.

**Remark:** Two vector spaces, say over the reals, are isomorphic precisely if they have the same dimension, and the dimension of $V\times W$ is completely determined by the dimensions of $V$ and $W$. So we can construct many examples where $X$ is isomorphic to $V\times W$ but $V\cap W\ne \{0\}$. As long as we get the dimensions of $V$ and $W$ right, we are pretty free in our choice of $V$ and $W$.

Comment: To be accurate we should say: "Two **finite** vector spaces,..." isn't it?

Comment: If you mean finite dimensional, that is not necessary. For any cardinal number $\kappa$, two vector spaces of dimension $\kappa$ over the reals are isomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be the space of infinite sequences of real numbers; then $X$ is isomorphic to $X\times X$.